# Qu'est-ce que "au plus vite"?

Tags: adjectifs, adverbes

[image]

Qu'est-ce que la position de "vite" en cet phrase? un adjectif ou un adverbe? si un adjectif, est-ce que un adjectif qualificatif attribut ou épithète?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dans cette phrase, *vite* est clairement un adverbe.

Voir [vite](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vite)

> §II.A.1 [Concernant un déplacement]En se déplaçant avec rapidité, en effectuant un grand parcours en un minimum de temps. Synon. rapidement

Comment: Oui! Absolument. Noter tout de même que l'OP s'était schtroumpfé la bonne question. (Si c'est un adjectif, que qualifie-t-il ?) question à laquelle on ne peut répondre que par *éloignons* qui est un verbe => vite =  Adverbe. Avec Peyo, même pas la peine de schtroumpfer un dico. Il est si rigoureux syntaxiquement et grammaticalement que même s'il avait dit *éloignons-le schtroumpfement* On aurait reconnu l'adverbe. Très fort ça!